# How to add in app purchase to react native app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, react-native-iap

So paid pages in my app, when a user click to open any of these pages i want to run a function to check if the product is purchased  and if it's not then buy the product, I have found two packages  which are react-native-iap and expo-in-app-purchase but did not find clear instructions on how to achieve the process i need..

```
const paidPage = async (productId , navTo) => {
 // PASS THE PRODUCT ID AND A FUNCTION THAT NAVIGATE TO THE PAGE 

// HERE I WANT TO CHECK IF THE PRODUCT IS PURCHASED, IF YES THEN NAVIGATE TO THE PAGE
// IF NO THEN PURCHASE THE PRODUCT 



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if you have already bought the product or not and check if it is still valid or not. Using react-native-iap package

```
RNIap.getPurchaseHistory().catch(() => {
    console.log("error fetching purchase history")
}).then((res) => {
   // here you will get all the purchase history
   // filter with the product id for which you want to check
   // if record exist that means you have to check its validity
})
```

checking validity is not straight forward. you need use code given bellow. However, `receipt` in `receiptBody` bellow can be any receipt since response does not shows its expiry date. Response has '`latest_receipt_info`' that contain all the purchase with expiry date from where you can filter the one you need.

```
const receiptBody = {
    "receipt-data" : receipt,
    "password" : "" //password from the App-Specific Shared Secret in appstoreconnect in-app-purchase section for the app
}
await RNIap.validateReceiptIos(receiptBody, true).then((receipt) => {
    try {
        const renewalHistory = receipt.latest_receipt_info 
        // it has all purchase with expiry date
        // filter for the one you are looking for
    } catch (error) {}
})
```

Receipt can be any receipt in `receiptBody` above so you can get current receipt which is fast to implement like bellow

```
    await RNIap.getReceiptIOS().then((res) => {
    currentReceipt = res
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using other third party libraries to handle receipt processing that provide clearer direction for how to handle in-app purchase.

One example is NamiML, which has a guide on how to check for active purchases here that has a react native example:

https://docs.namiml.com/docs/react-to-changes-to-entitlements

The code for what you want to check using the NamiML library looks like:

```
NativeModules.NamiEntitlementManagerBridge.isEntitlementActive("premium_access", (active) => { 
    if (active) {
    // react to entitlement being active
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For react native iap, if the user purchases the app but they already own it, you'll get a purchase error code of "E_ALREADY_OWNED". You can use [async storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/) to store a variable to check if the page has already been purchased; if not, then go to the page and award it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentPurchaseError) {
      if (
        currentPurchaseError.code === "E_ALREADY_OWNED" &&
        !isPagePurchased
      ) {
        setAndStorePagePurchase(true)
      }
    }
  }, [currentPurchaseError])
```

See [this example](https://www.doabledanny.com/react-native-iap-example-android) for how to implement this into a full simple app.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [RevenueCat](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/reactnative) with relative success recently. They're free if you make less than 10k(?) in a year through the app. With their sdk `react-native-purchases` I implemented something like this, with the consideration that I only have 1 IAP:

```
      try {
        const purchaserInfo = await Purchases.getPurchaserInfo();
        if (purchaserInfo && Object.entries(purchaserInfo.entitlements.active).length) {
          setActive(true); //There exists an entry for the purchase they made, 
                           //meaning they're an active customer
        } else {
          setActive(false);
        }

        const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
        if (offerings && offerings.current) {
          setPrice(offerings.all.fullVersionOffering.availablePackages[0].product.price_string);
        } else {
          setPrice('$1.99');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```